# Equivalent of SetUserData and GetUserData on XMLNode

Tags: c#, xml

In Java, You can use GetUserData and SetUserData to attach arbitrary objects on a XML Node to use at runtime while processing a DOM. Is there an equivalent in C#? Is there any way to do this in C# other than extending XMLNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlNode` is a bit obsolete. You should be using LINQ to XML.

The base class of all objects in LINQ to XML is [`XObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.aspx). This class has an [`AddAnnotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.addannotation.aspx) method that allows you to attach arbitrary data to an `XObject`.

Comment: Thank you, while your answer is extremely helpful to me I will have to accept @Dan-o's answer because it directly addresses the problem described. I am wokring on porting a Java solution into C# and can't immidiately switch from XmlNode to LINQ, as soon as I can build the code and get it to work I will use your advice and siwtch to Linq.

Comment: Why not just use `XNode` instead of `XmlNode`? Is it that big of a difference?

Comment: I found an almost one to one mapping (aside from Set/GetUserData) between Node and XmlNode, which makes it much easier to port the code. I will try Switching to Linq and Xnode today and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that built into the framework.

You can achieve the same thing in a couple different ways.

**Subclass `XmlNode`:**

```
class CustomXmlNode : XmlNode {
    public Object Tag {get; set;}
}
/* Tag is a common name for user-defined data in .NET */
```

**Create a `Dictionary`:**

```
Dictionary<XmlNode, Object> xmlMap = new Dictionary<XmlNode, Object>();
/* for each node you load, create a new dictionary entry */
```